# How to name a function that accepts null values, C#?

Tags: c#, .net, function

I need to create a function that accepts null as a parameter and safely returns null without exception.

```
MyObject CreateMyObject(string objectName)
{
   if(objectName == null)
       return null;

   // create and return object otherwise 
}
```

There are thousands of calls of this function all around the program, checking for null values before calling CreateMyObject increases amount of code and dev time. Nulls returned by this function are safely ignored at a later stages in a program.

What would be an appropriate name for such function so the functionality is obvious for the caller?

Comment: Well, in most cases, this is a Try* method, e.g. TryParse

Comment: I wouldn't use nulls, try implementing the null object pattern

Comment: @MareInfinitus "Try" naming isn't for null handling per se but rather for safe execution of operation which can fail. OP, before wanting special naming to avoid consumers to "recheck" you should test if that test has really an impact ; JIT can do a decent job maybe and leverage that "cost" for you

Comment: Not really answering your question, but if you are using resharper you could add [`[ContractAnnotation("null => null; notnull => notnull")]`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/2016.1/Contract_Annotations.html) to let it's analyzer know about the behavior. Or do `MyObject CreateMyObject([CanBeNull] string objectName)`

Comment: seems like wierd behaviour. calling it with null works but returns null, but it would normally return a valid object. Odd semantics

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ extensions methods which doesn't throw an exception if nothing has been matched are sufixed with `OrDefault`.

Therefore, you may follow this convention too and change your method identifier to `CreateMyObjectOrDefault`.

Or, actually, as @RB. has suggested in some comment on this answer, since `MyObject` is a reference type, you could simply call your method as `CreateMyObjectOrNull`.

### Suggestion

Why don't you turn this method into an extension method:

```
public static class ObjectExtensions
{
     public static MyObject CreateMyObject(this string name)
     {
           Contract.Requires(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name));

           // create and return object otherwise 
     }
}
```

...and you use the new and shiny [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) when you call it?

```
string text = "whatever";

// This is equivalent to your approach and you're using regular C#
// syntax and you don't need to re-invent the wheel ;)
MyObject myObject = text?.CreateMyObject();
```

Also, learn more about [*code contracts*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264808(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand what's going on with `Contract.Requires`.

Comment: ooo - good answer

Comment: @pm100 Thanks! Well, I've just limited it to follow BCL naming conventions :)

Comment: Except in this case you know what the default value is going to be, so you could name it `CreateMyObjectOrNull`. Note that, while this is perfectly logical, it sounds really odd - I think this suggests the premise of the question may be flawed.

Comment: @RB. Yeah, you're right

Comment: @RB. I've updated my answer with your suggestion ;)